# How can I send messages to content.js evertime when I changed the tab on the top in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to ask my chrome extension to do something by using `content.js` when I changed the tab **on the top**.

So I need to connect `content.js` when the tab on the top is changed.

I try to use `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener()` and `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()` to listen the changes.It works well when I open a **new tab**,but when I switch the tab between **tabs have been opened**,it doesn't work.

The problem is,althought `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener()` can listen the changes,it seems that `chrome.runtime.onMessage/chrome.runtime.sendMessage/chrome.tabs.sendMessage/chrome.runtime.onconnect` can't work in it(`chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener()`).

This is the warn：

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Is the problem of my using way?

My code:

```
{   
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "test",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "test",
   "background": {
    "page": "background.js",
    "persisten": false
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "test"
   },
   "content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_idle"
      }
   ],
    "permissions":
    [
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "storage",
        "cookies",
        "*://*/*"
   ]
}
```

```
//background.js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(moveInfo){
    chrome.tabs.get(moveInfo.tabId,function(tab){
        alert(tab.url);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{Url:tab.url});
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    alert(tab.url);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{Url:tab.url});
});
```

```
//content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    alert("get the message");
});
```

Thank you very much if you can help me!